# не работает анимация у glb

Tags: javascript, three.js, animate

Загрузка модели:

```
function loadAnimatedModel(path)
{
    var loader = new GLTFLoader();
    loader.load(path, function (gltf) {
        var mesh = gltf.scene.children[0];
        var clip = gltf.animations[0];

        // установка параметров анимации (скорость воспроизведения и стартовый кадр)
        mixer.clipAction(clip, mesh).setDuration(1).startAt(0).play();

        mesh.position.set(0, 30, 0);
        mesh.rotation.y = Math.PI / 8;
        mesh.scale.set(0.2, 0.2, 0.2);
        
        mesh.castShadow = true;
        mesh.receiveShadow = true;

        scene.add(mesh);
        morphs.push(mesh);
    });
}
```

Функция requestAnimationFrame:

```
var delta = clock.getDelta;
mixer.update( delta );
```

В средстве 3д просмотра модель анимирована, но на сцене она не двигается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После getDelta должны быть скобки